# Should I regexp.test before I string.replace?

Tags: javascript, regex

When I want to replace some parts of a string, should I call replace directly like this?

```
var r1 = /"\+((:?[\w\.]+)(:?(:?\()(:?.*?)(:?\))|$){0,1})\+"/g;
arg = arg.replace(r1, function(outer, inner){
    return eval(inner);
});
```

Or test for a match first, and then replace if it's a hit, like this?

```
var r1 = /"\+((:?[\w\.]+)(:?(:?\()(:?.*?)(:?\))|$){0,1})\+"/g;
if (r1.test(arg)) {
    arg = arg.replace(r1, function(outer, inner){
        return eval(inner);
    });
}
```

I guess this boils down to how the string.replace(regex, string) function works. Will it go into my callback even if there is no match, or will it then simply return arg? In that case I assume the calling replace directly is the right way to go to avoid having the regex engine match the string twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don have to use `test`. The function in `replace` only executed when a match occurs.

- No matches: No function (eval) call
- 1 match: 1 call
- 2 matches: 2 calls
- etc.

Also, why are you using eval? `eval` executes the parameter, as if it's a JavaScript expression. Since you know the input format, it's likely that you're able to achieve the same behaviour without eval.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'm using this to extract some information from my document as is in the browser. The string comes from customer specific configuration on the server. Basically I'm either evaluating a function call or getting the contents of a namespaced variable. I don't know of any other way to get this evaluated than using eval. If there is another way, please advice.

Comment: `eval` seems to be a good option in this case. Make sure that the source is reliable, though.